# How to make a github action that checks if a program crashes

Tags: github-actions

I want to create a github action that:

1. compiles a program
2. Runs the program
3. Succeeds if the program does not crash within these 15 seconds.

I understand how to do the first two parts, how would one go about implementing the third part?

Comment: Please show what you have tried and how that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Incase anyone ever runs into this issue in the future:

```
command_to_build_the_program
timeout 5s command_to_run_the_program
if [ $? == "124" ]; then
    echo "The software did not crash"
    exit 0
fi
echo "The software crashed"
exit 1
```